# Como puedo crear un objeto vector dentro de una cola?

Tags: c#, .net

el problema es el siguiente trate de crear el objeto vector en este caso productos, y el objeto lo uso para darlo como parametro de un constructor de la clase almacen, almacen tambien tiene el constructor sucursal el cual me guardara el nombre de la sucursal, porque necesito que el codigo guarde en un solo nodo lo que es nombre de la sucursal y productos (tambien mostrarlos) que este tiene, el problema es que al momento de que trato de guardar todo el valor que le doy de sucursal se cambia con el valor que le doy a productos
adjunto codigo

**clase productos**

```
public class produtos
    {
        private string nombre;
        private string categoria;
        public string Categoria 
        {
            get { return categoria; }
            set { categoria = value; }
        }
        public string Nombre 
        {
            get { return nombre; }
            set { nombre = value; }
        }
        public produtos(string nombre, string categorias) 
        {
            this.nombre = nombre;
            this.categoria = categorias; 
        }
    }
}
```

**clase almacen**

```
public class almacen
    {
        private string sucursal;
        private produtos[] productos;
        public string Sucursal 
        {
            get { return sucursal; }
            set { sucursal = value; }
        }
        public produtos[] Productos 
        {
            get { return productos; }
            set { productos = value; }
        }
        public almacen(produtos[] productos,string sucursal) 
        {
            this.productos = productos;
            this.sucursal = sucursal;
        }
        public almacen(string sucursal) 
        {
            this.sucursal = sucursal;
        }
    }
```

**clase main o program**

```
class Program 
    {
        public static void Main(string[] args) 
        {
            produtos[] productos = new produtos[1];
            productos [0] = new produtos("hola", "mundo");
            almacen sucursal = new almacen("sucursal central");
            sucursal = new almacen(productos,"mundo");
            Queue<almacen>colasucursales=new Queue<almacen>();
            colasucursales.Enqueue(sucursal);
            foreach (almacen mostrar in colasucursales) 
            {
                
                Console.WriteLine(mostrar.Sucursal);

            }
            Console.ReadKey();
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Saludos**

Tu clase `almacen` tiene dos constructores:

- `public almacen(produtos[] productos,string sucursal)`
- `public almacen(string sucursal)`

En el `Main` de tú código:

```
// Crear el array de un elemento
produtos[] productos = new produtos[1];
// Inicializas el primer elemento poniendo la propiedad categoria = "mundo"
productos [0] = new produtos("hola", "mundo");
// Crear un objeto almacen con su propiedad sucursal = "sucursal central"
almacen sucursal = new almacen("sucursal central");
// Vueles a crear el objeto (eliminando la inicialización anterior) pasando productos e iniciando su propiedad sucursal="mundo"
sucursal = new almacen(productos,"mundo");
```

Tu código esta haciendo lo que le indicas; me da la impresión que tu última inicialización (del fragmento de código que refiero arriba) debe ser:

```
sucursal = new almacen(productos,"sucursal central");
```

o *de manera directa* para *omitir la segunda inicialización* quedaría solo:

```
almacen sucursal = new almacen(productos, "sucursal central");
```

o en su defecto agregar a `almacen` un método para agregar solo los productos.

Comment: gracias,  ya entendí el porque, ahora lo corrijo